# Why does this end up in an infinite loop in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, infinite-loop

I'm making a tower desence game for a game jam in HTML5. I have a subroutine for the AI of the towers. However, for some reason, this function call without a loop ends up in an infinite loop. It only happens when there are at least two towers.

```
function aiTower(id){
    if(id === 1)alert("towerId = 1 call 1");
    var l = zamerajCiel(id);
    if (l !==  null) towers[id].shoot(l.x,l.y);
    if(id === 1)alert("towerId = 1 call 2");
};
```

The loop that calls it:

```
function aiLoop(){
    for(i=0;i<enemies.length;i++){
        aiMon(i);
    }
    for(i=0;i<towers.length;i++){
        aiTower(i);
            if(i === 1)alert("towerId = 1 call 3");
    }
}
```

The debug msgs are alternating "towerId = 1 call 1" and "towerId = 1 call 2", so the problem probably isn't in the aiLoop(). Also, I have used a regexp to search my code for aiTower(). These were the only two occurences.

Comment: I think we will need the code for `.shoot` and `zamerajCiel' as well. Just an advice: use `console.log('msg u want to see')`, if you use firebug it will be such a great logging tool. https://getfirebug.com/logging

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make `i` local to the function by providing `var i`. It is likely that you modify it elsewhere.